# Write the following limit as a derivative and evaluate.

Tags: calculus

Write the following limit as a derivative and evaluate. 
$$\lim_{x\to \frac \pi4} {\tan(x)−1\over x−\frac \pi4}$$ 
the derivative $$f'(x)= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} {f(x+\Delta x)−f(x)\over \Delta x}$$

I have seen similar problems here, but they not involved $\tan$ and it has confused me.
I'm not familiar with L'Hopital rule. Please do not suggest it.
Therefore, if $1= \tan (\frac \pi4)$ and if we set, $h = x - \frac \pi4$, hence $$\lim_{h\to 0} {\tan(\frac \pi4 +h)−\tan(\frac \pi4)\over h}$$
$$\tan(\frac \pi4 +h)= \frac{\tan(\frac\pi4)+\tan(h)} {1-\tan(\frac\pi4)\tan(h)}$$
so, $$\frac{\tan(\frac\pi4)+\tan(h)} {1-\tan(\frac\pi4)\tan(h)}-\tan(\frac\pi4)\over h$$
$$\frac{1+\tan(h)} {1-tan(h)}-1\over h$$
make it to the common denominator
we get $$2\tan(h)\over h(1-\tan(h))$$
what should I do next?
any help will be appreciated.
is there any other ways to evaluate?

Comment: In your limit, when $x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}$, you should replace that with $h\rightarrow 0$ since when $x$ approaches $\frac{\pi}{4}$, $h$ approaches $0$.

Comment: You say "we get $\frac{\tan(h)}{1-\tan(h)}$."  Where does that come from?

Comment: Observe that your limit is actually *the definition* of a derivative.  So, if you know how to take the derivative of $\tan$, then you're done because that limit is actually the derivative at $\pi/4$.

Comment: i ve already recalculate it. very lost with this question.

Comment: Please show your work between the limit and the next step that I mentioned above.  When evaluating a limit, the variable of the limit (in this case $h$) should no longer appear.

Comment: @Michael Burr i did

Comment: But, you dropped the limits, they very much matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle f^{\prime}(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, $\;\;$ letting $f(x)=\tan x$ gives

$\hspace{.88 in}\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan x-1}{x-\frac{\pi}{4}}=f^{\prime}\big(\frac{\pi}{4}\big)=\sec^2\frac{\pi}{4}=(\sqrt{2})^2=2$

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. Use the hint to find

$$\lim_{h\to 0} {\tan(\frac \pi4 +h)−\tan(\frac \pi4)\over h}=\tan'(\frac\pi4).$$

Comment: $\tan' \frac \pi4$ is 0, therefore h from denominator disappeared?

Comment: No, this is not what the notation means.

Comment: soo, my limit will be equal to 0?

Comment: No, $2$. Scratch your head harder.

Comment: ok, this limit is my derivative, right? the derivative of $\tan(\frac \pi4)$ is 0

Comment: i can't get it.

Comment: $$\tan'(x)\Big|_{x=\pi/4}$$

Comment: @Sarah $(tan(\frac{\pi}{4}))'\neq tan'(\frac{\pi}{4})$

Comment: aaahh, damn. so it's 2

Comment: yes @Sarah it's 2